# iOS 12-only Crash on -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore upsertPropertyRecord:]

Tags: google-analytics

Unable to reproduce but getting lots of crashes reported via crashlytics.

See crash log below. If more info is needed please let me know...

Crashing only on devices running iOS 12.0/12.1

Using GoogleAnalytics 3.17.0 (latest)

Crash occurs at:

```
8  -----                          0x10148534c -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore upsertPropertyRecord:] + 4383150924
```

Help and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

> Crashed: GAIThread
>
> 0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x1bf912f3c
>   _os_unfair_lock_unowned_abort + 36
>
> 1  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x1bf914524
>   _os_unfair_lock_unlock_slow + 144
>
> 2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1c017e18c sqlite3_randomness +
>   4368
>
> 3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1c015d878 sqlite3_value_text +
>   26356
>
> 4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1c015d250 sqlite3_value_text +
>   24780
>
> 5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1c0128434 sqlite3_finalize + 3732
>
> 6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1c01557d0 sqlite3_step + 66844
>
> 7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1c0145464 sqlite3_step + 432
>
> 8  -----                          0x10148534c
>   -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore upsertPropertyRecord:] + 4383150924
>
> 9  -----                          0x101484ddc
>   -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore nextHitNumberForTrackingId:clientId:] + 4383149532
>
> 10 -----                          0x10147eb00 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher
>   queueDispatch:] + 4383124224
>
> 11 -----                          0x10147e91c -[GAIBatchingDispatcher
>   queueModel:] + 4383123740
>
> 12 Foundation                     0x1c07bb5a0 __NSThreadPerformPerform
>   + 336
>
> 13 CoreFoundation                 0x1bfc9a5b8
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24
>
> 14 CoreFoundation                 0x1bfc9a538 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 +
>   88
>
> 15 CoreFoundation                 0x1bfc99e1c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 +
>   176
>
> 16 CoreFoundation                 0x1bfc94ce8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1040
>
> 17 CoreFoundation                 0x1bfc945b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific +
>   436
>
> 18 Foundation                     0x1c06886a4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop)
>   runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
>
> 19 Foundation                     0x1c06c4094 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop)
>   run] + 88
>
> 20 -----                          0x10146bf14 +[GAI threadMain:] +
>   4383047444
>
> 21 Foundation                     0x1c07bb3b0 **NSThread__start** +
>   1040
>
> 22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1bf9252fc _pthread_body + 128
>
> 23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1bf92525c _pthread_start + 48
>
> 24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1bf928d08 thread_start + 4

--

Update:

I made a couple of changes that seemed to have helped. The app is still crashing but less frequently. Also I added log statements to help pinpoint where and when it is crashing.

The change I made that seemed to help was increasing the value for dispatchInterval (previous set to 20)...

```
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 60;
```

Also, the crash only seems to occur when the app is launched and/or becomes active while trying to track an event in the app delegate method...

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        ...
        GA_EVENT(@"App Launch", @"", @"App Launched", 0);
        // NOTE: GA_EVENT defines a custom method that creates the event (GAIDictionaryBuilder) 
        // and invokes the GAITracker's send method with the event per usual.        
        // This approach is used throughout the app and was working fine prior 
        // to iOS 12, but is now causing a crash here for some reason
        ...
}
```

Lastly, in the event that this is a bug with GA SDK, I created an issue in their bug tracker. From my research, the last time this crash was reported it seemed to have required an update to their SDK. So, perhaps that's the case here as well. We'll see if I hear anything back from the Google gods...

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117476933

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for the problem? If yes, please share.

Answer (score 0):

We have found the solution to this problem after spending sleepless days and nights. The issue was occurring because of the Apsalar SDK in our case. If you are using Apsalar SDK in your project, I highly recommend you to move from Apsalar to Singular SDK. Singular SDK covers all the functionality provided by Apsalar. So you need not worry about missing any functionality or changing a hell lot of code.

You can download the Singular SDK from the following link: https://support.singular.net/hc/en-us/articles/115000497903-Integrating-the-Singular-SDK